# How to convert a string into JSON using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

The string to convert:

`[{"description": "Hi","id":2,"img":"hi.png"},{"description": "pet","id":10,"img":"pet.png"},{"description": "Hello! :D","id":12,"img":"hello.png"}]`

The code to convert the string:

`var json = JSON(stringLiteral: stringJSON)`

The string is converted to JSON and when I try to count how many blocks are inside this JSON (expected answer = 3), I get 0.

`print(json.count)`

Console Output: `0`

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: If I remember it correctly it's: json.array.count

Comment: When I print the "json" it shows me all the data, but when I print "json.count" it shows me 0 and not 3 :C

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fix it on this way.

I will use the variable "string" as the variable what contains the JSON.

1.

encode the sting with NSData like this

```
var encodedString : NSData = (string as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

2. un-encode the string encoded (this may be sound a little bit weird hehehe):

   var finalJSON = JSON(data: encodedString)

Then you can do whatever you like with this JSON.

Like get the number of sections in it (this was the real question) with

`finalJSON.count` or `print(finalJSON[0])` or whatever you like to do.

Answer (score 60):

Actually, there was a built-in function in SwifyJSON called `parse`

```
/**
 Create a JSON from JSON string
- parameter string: Normal json string like '{"a":"b"}'

- returns: The created JSON
*/
public static func parse(string:String) -> JSON {
    return string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        .flatMap({JSON(data: $0)}) ?? JSON(NSNull())
}
```

Note that

```
var json = JSON.parse(stringJSON)
```

its now changed to

```
var json = JSON.init(parseJSON:stringJSON)
```

Comment: Constructor parameter has been renamed parseJSON → JSON.init(parseJSON: stringJSON)

Answer (score 5):

There is a built-in parser in SwiftyJSON:

```
let json = JSON.init(parseJSON: responseString)
```

Don't forget to import SwiftyJSON!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using as follows:

```
let yourString = NSMutableString()

let dataToConvert = yourString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

let json = JSON(data: dataToConvert!)

print("\nYour string: " + String(describing: json))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift4**

```
let json = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8).flatMap({try? JSON(data: $0)}) ?? JSON(NSNull())
```

Comment: It doesn't compile because $0 is UInt8 and not a valid parameter type for JSON(data:). Despite not compiling, I don't see how this would result in json because it makes an array (flatMap).

Comment: The part `$0` is used within ForEach loops, so it could technically work.